# How to resolve the cif2cell TypeError?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, cif

I have encountered an error using cif2cell while covering a CIF file from COD to quantum ESPRESSO format. The error is as follows.

> command typed:
> **$cif2cell crystal.cif -p quantum-espresso -o crystal.in**

> ***Warning: Space group operation check failed for Hall symbol -P 1 (H-M symbol P-1).
> ***Warning: Site occupancies not found, assuming all occupancies = 1. Traceback (most recent call last): File “/usr/local/bin/cif2cell”,
> line 1574, in  docstring = StandardDocstring() File
> “/usr/local/bin/cif2cell”, line 1021, in StandardDocstring tmpstring2
> += “. Reference number : “+ref.databasecode
> TypeError: must be str, not NoneType

This seems to be a bug in the Quantum Mobile platform too.

Comment: If that program (cif2cell) is still maintained, it's best to report such problems to the developers.

Comment: @marcin Do you refer to *this [cif2cell](https://pypi.org/project/cif2cell/), release 2.0.0a3  by Mar 3, 2021 ?

Comment: Is the `.cif` plausible in first place (e.g., by [checkcif](https://checkcif.iucr.org/))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way around it you can include a NULL database code [using the **_cod_database_code** keyword ]under the **data_global** keyword in CIF and it will work.

example:

```
data_global
_cod_database_code               None
```

This worked for me. Since the **cod_databse_code** is just for printing the first few comments in the input file created by cif2cell it will resolve the issue without affecting the crystal information which we intend to provide.